# How to get value of users id on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, firebaseui

**I want to know how to have the reference uid of the users but I don't know how :(...**

My database:

[image]

My code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua1zd.jpg

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UsersDatabaseModel> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UsersDatabaseModel>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Registered Users").child("userID").child("Other Account Settings"), UsersDatabaseModel.class)
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the UID of the user who is currently signed in to Firebase Authentication, you can do so with:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

You can then stuff that into your database reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
  .getReference("Registered Users")
  .child(uid)
  .child("Other Account Settings")
```

Comment: I want to get the general uid reference of all users, not the current user

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but it could be that's because there's information missing from your question. When you step through your code in a debugger, which line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I have a RecyclerView adapter from Firebase and I want to get the name and other data of my users, but when using my code it gives me null because I don't have the uid reference. What I want to get is that, the uid of my users in general. :(

Comment: So you want to show a list of all accounts across all users?

Comment: You might want to edit your question (there's a link right under it), to make that more explicit. Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the adapters in FirebaseUI for that. Those are designed to show a flat list of results from a `DatabaseReference` or a `Query`. So if you want to show a list of accounts across all users with FirebaseUI, you'll have to store precisely that: a single list of accounts. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested